# How to retrieve email based on sender, sent date and subject using graph api with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm working on a simple python script to help me retrieve email in office365 user mailbox based on the following parameters, `sentdatetime, sender or from address and subject`.

As of current, am able to get the access token using msal, however the email api call does not work. I get an `error 401`. From graph explorer the query works however in the script it's not working.

My app registration is assigned application permission for mail, i selected everything under mail permissions. see below permissions
[image]

Below is my script so far, what am i doing wrong.

```
import msal
import json
import requests

def get_access_token():
    tenantID = '9a13fbbcb90fa2'
    authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenantID
    clientID = 'xxx'
    clientSecret = 'yyy'
    scope = ['https://outlook.office365.com/.default']
    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(clientID, authority=authority, client_credential = clientSecret)
    access_token = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
    return access_token

# token block
access_token = get_access_token()
token = access_token['access_token']


# Set the parameters for the email search
date_sent = "2023-01-22T21:13:24Z"
mail_subject = "Test Mail"
sender = "bernardberbell@gmail.com"
mailuser = "bernardmwanza@bernardcomms.onmicrosoft.com"

# Construct the URL for the Microsoft Graph API
url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{}/mailFolders/Inbox/Messages?$select=id,sentDateTime,subject,from&$filter=contains(subject, '{}') and from/emailAddress/address eq '{}' and SentDateTime gt '{}'".format(mailuser, mail_subject, sender, date_sent)

# Set the headers for the API call
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

# Send the API request and get the response
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response)

# # Parse the response as JSON
# data = json.loads(response.text)

# print(data)
```

Below is the error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scope is wrong for the Graph API this

```
scope = ['https://outlook.office365.com/.default']
```

Will give you a token that has an audience of outlook.office365.com which is okay for IMAP4 but not for the Graph which requires the audience to be https://graph.microsoft.com

so your scope for the graph should be

```
scope = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']
```

You can check your token use jwt.io and verify it.

Comment: hello Glen Scales, i modified the scope as suggested, however i get the following error. `{'error': {'code': 'BadRequest', 'message': 'Invalid filter clause', 'innerError': {'date': '2023-01-23T06:30:23', 'request-id': '524139ad-c867-4511-aaf7-0e4357f93080', 'client-request-id': '524139ad-c867-4511-aaf7-0e4357f93080'}}}`

Comment: remove the apostrophes around the date that will make the parser treat it as a string and it will fail the query